# Find unused site assets

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to identify any unused images in Site Assets in order to delete them?  Alternatively, is it possible to find out on what pages a given asset is currently being used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have a way to find out the images being used from Site Assets library, because they might be referencing these images by placing in the script editor in that case you will loose if you delete any images. Even though you get the last modified for those images it won't help you where the image is referring to.

I would say for time being move the images to a New Library and keep there for couple of weeks if no one complaints in a weeks then you go ahead delete those images.

Answer (score 0):

For now we do not have ways to know if the images are used by any sort of reference. Move images to new library one by one could be a possible but troublesome approach.